# Chrome add padding around the page on iPhone's with a notch

Tags: html, css, iphone, google-chrome

On iPhone X (and other iPhones with a notch) in landscape orientation Google Chrome browser add an additional padding on right and left sides around page, while Safari don't. How it's possible to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone X has the notorious notch and home bar. Apple doesn't content to be covered by those items unless you explicitly tell it to.

You can add this to fix your problem:

```
padding: env(safe-area-inset);
```

Source is found [here](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x)

And fix the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

This tells your iPhone to add the necessary padding.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a known problem for a long time, 
it´s easy to fix:

```
 *{ margin : 0; padding : 0;box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Sometime you need to use "-webkit and moz" too.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```